# How to use array_push() while using join query in mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json

> rent_property (table name)

```
id     fullName    propertyName

1       Kani       House Name1

2       B          House Name2

3       C          House Name3

4       Sarvan     House Name4
```

> rent_amenity (table name)

```
rentamenityId         rentPropertyId       amenityName

1                         1                 Lift
2                         1                 Gym
3                         1                 Swimming Pool

4                         4                 Lift
5                         4                 Gym
```

> mysql query

```
    $sql = "SELECT a.id,a.fullName,a.propertyName FROM rent_property a LEFT JOIN rent_amenity b ON  a.id = b.rentPropertyId WHERE a.city='1' AND a.propertyType IN ( '1','2' ) AND b.amenityName IN ( 'Gym' )  AND a.approveStatus!='Inactive' GROUP BY a.id order by a.id desc ";

    $result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
```

> my dynamic function

```
public function GetJoinRecord($query_string){

        $con = $this->DBConnection();
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$query_string);
        if(@mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

                while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $record[] = $data;
                }
                mysqli_free_result($query);

            }

            mysqli_close($con); 
            return $record;
    }
```

> print_r($result);

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [fullName] => Sarvan
            [propertyName] => House Name4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [fullName] => Kani
            [propertyName] => House Name1
        )

)
```

upto now every thing is working fine,here after i want to take the **amenityName** based property and i want to push the amenities in $result array

```
$result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                       $propertyId = $value['id'];
                       $farrs = array();
                        $q1 = "SELECT * FROM rent_amenity WHERE `rentPropertyId` = '$propertyId' AND amenityStatus != 'Deactive'";
                        $amenities = $this->GetJoinRecord($q1);
                        foreach($amenities as $key => $value){
                            $rowame['rentamenityId'] = $value['rentamenityId'];
                            $rowame['rentPropertyId'] =$value['rentPropertyId'];
                            $rowame['amenityName'] = $value['amenityName'];
                            $rowame['amenityStatus'] = $value['amenityStatus'];
                            array_push($farrs,$rowame); 
                        }
                        $row['amenities'] = $farrs;
                        array_push($result,$row);
            }
            $response_array['status']='success';
            $response_array['message']='Data Found.';
            $response_array['data']=array('rent_id'=>$result);
            $this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
```

> I am getting output like this

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Data Found.",
"data": {
    "rent_id": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "fullName": "Sarvan",
            "propertyName": "House Name4"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "fullName": "Kani",
            "propertyName": "House Name1"
        },
        {
            "amenities": [
                {
                    "rentamenityId": "9",
                    "rentPropertyId": "4",
                    "amenityName": "Lift",
                    "amenityStatus": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "rentamenityId": "10",
                    "rentPropertyId": "4",
                    "amenityName": "Gym",
                    "amenityStatus": "Active"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "amenities": [
                {
                    "rentamenityId": "1",
                    "rentPropertyId": "1",
                    "amenityName": "Lift",
                    "amenityStatus": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "rentamenityId": "2",
                    "rentPropertyId": "1",
                    "amenityName": "Gym",
                    "amenityStatus": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "rentamenityId": "3",
                    "rentPropertyId": "1",
                    "amenityName": "Swimming Pool",
                    "amenityStatus": "Active"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

**but this is not my expected ouput ,here besed on my table and sql query records comming correctly, i am not able make my expected JSON Format**

> My Expected JSON ouput like is

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Data Found.",
"data": {
    "rent_id": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "fullName": "Sarvan",
            "propertyName": "House Name4",
             "amenities":[
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"4",
                       "rentPropertyId":"4",
                       "amenityName":"Lift"
                    },
                     {
                       "rentamenityId":"5",
                       "rentPropertyId":"4",
                       "amenityName":"Gym"
                    }
                 ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "fullName": "A",
            "propertyName": "House Name1",
            "amenities":[
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"1",
                       "rentPropertyId":"1",
                       "amenityName":"Lift"
                    },
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"2",
                       "rentPropertyId":"1",
                       "amenityName":"Gym"
                    },
                    {
                       "rentamenityId":"3",
                       "rentPropertyId":"1",
                       "amenityName":"Swimming Pool"
                    }
                 ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

> My Code

```
    $sql = "SELECT a.id,a.fullName,a.propertyName FROM rent_property a LEFT JOIN rent_amenity b ON  a.id = b.rentPropertyId WHERE a.city='1' AND a.propertyType IN ( '1','2' ) AND b.amenityName IN ( 'Gym' )  AND a.approveStatus!='Inactive' GROUP BY a.id order by a.id desc ";
$result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
                foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                           $propertyId = $value['id'];
                           $farrs = array();
                            $q1 = "SELECT * FROM rent_amenity WHERE `rentPropertyId` = '$propertyId' AND amenityStatus != 'Deactive'";
                            $amenities = $this->GetJoinRecord($q1);
                            foreach($amenities as $key => $value){
                                $rowame['rentamenityId'] = $value['rentamenityId'];
                                $rowame['rentPropertyId'] =$value['rentPropertyId'];
                                $rowame['amenityName'] = $value['amenityName'];
                                $rowame['amenityStatus'] = $value['amenityStatus'];
                                array_push($farrs,$rowame); 
                            }
                            $row['amenities'] = $farrs;
                            array_push($result,$row);
                }
                $response_array['status']='success';
                $response_array['message']='Data Found.';
                $response_array['data']=array('rent_id'=>$result);
                $this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
```

Comment: post only code, which is causing issue

Comment: @Ravi, please see post, i posted my code down below,i am using this code but i am not getting my expected json output

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code as below: first create  new result which contain combine data from both query then at last add that result to data

```
$new_result = array();
$result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
           $propertyId = $value['id'];

           $farrs = array();
            $q1 = "SELECT * FROM rent_amenity WHERE `rentPropertyId` = '$propertyId' AND amenityStatus != 'Deactive'";
            $amenities = $this->GetJoinRecord($q1);
            foreach($amenities as $key => $value){
                $rowame['rentamenityId'] = $value['rentamenityId'];
                $rowame['rentPropertyId'] =$value['rentPropertyId'];
                $rowame['amenityName'] = $value['amenityName'];
                $rowame['amenityStatus'] = $value['amenityStatus'];
                array_push($farrs,$rowame); 
            }
            $row['id'] = $value['id'];
            $row['fullName'] = $value['fullName'];
            $row['propertyName'] = $value['propertyName'];
            $row['amenities'] = $farrs;
            array_push($new_result,$row);
}
$response_array['status']='success';
$response_array['message']='Data Found.';
$response_array['data']=array('rent_id'=>$new_result);
$this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
```